# Set Storybook canvas zoom

Tags: storybook

Is there any way to set the zoom level for a storybook canvas in either `argTypes` or `parameters`?

[image: storybook toolbar]

Comment: You can try to read this to solve your problem. (https://community.esri.com/t5/classic-esri-story-maps-questions/using-different-zoom-levels-in-story-map-tour/td-p/47894). Tell me if it works

Comment: @Leonardo - thanks for the comment but your link has no relevance to storybook...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the workaround for this.
Just wrap your template in the `<div>` element and set zoom attribute on it.

```
const Template: Story<IComponentProps> = (args) => (
    <div style={{ zoom: 0.3 }}>
        <Component {...args} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: This does indeed work - shame Storybook doesn't have an official way of doing it.